Rendering html5 video in an iframe with Geckoview vs WebView and settings.domStorageEnabled related issues
I recently noticed that an html5 video in an iframe could not be well rendered with geckoview.
Here is a link to a youtube video example you will see that a part of the video is off the screen :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nK9hD9_SAdU
The problem also exists using WebView but using settings.domStorageEnabled=true solves it. Is there some equivalent setting with geckoview ? I'm not sure but it seems this is related to localstorage  and I don't know why it is related to the way the video is rendrered.  Also there must be a solution has the video is well rendered using firefox focus.
I tried the following setting but no success
runtime.getSettings().javaScriptEnabled=true
runtime.getSettings().extensionsWebAPIEnabled=true

